# CLion "Expression can be simplified" message on bitwise operation

Tags: c, clion

I was working on a C project and i wrote the following line to check if the most significant bit of an int8_t is 1:

```
if (f & 0b10000000 == 0b10000000) {
```

and CLion threw up a warning, telling me 'Expression can be simplified to "f != 0"'

Would I be right in saying this is incorrect? I read over bitwise operations to be sure and I still feel like these are not equivalent operations, for instance f = 1 would return false with my expression, but this message is making me doubt myself.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Also, this is not valid C. Changing tag to C++.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker They might be using a C compiler with non-standard extension , it would be better to obtain clarification from OP

Comment: BTW `f < 0` is a clearer way to perform that test.  `0b10000000` has value `128` which is out of range of `int8_t`

Comment: @M.M I was using GCC and it has been working, didn't even realize that it wasn't standard C. Also that test is a good shout, I didn't think of that approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bitwise "and" operator `&` has lower precedence than `==`.

Therefore, your expression `if (f & 0b10000000 == 0b10000000)` is equivalent to `if (f & (0b10000000 == 0b10000000))`.

If you just want to test bit 7, try `if (f & 0b10000000)`. Any non-zero value will be treated as "true".

Also, yes: CLion is wrong. Your original expression is equivalent to `if (f & 1)`,  which tests bit 0 (probably not what you intended).